# Trouble getting between steps when solving integral

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I've having a lot of trouble trying to figure out how they're getting from the step in blue to the one in red. Can some one please explain that?

Comment: Simply factor out a $u$ and then factor out a $\frac 1 {15}$.

Comment: Bring $\frac{1}{5}u^5-\frac{2}{3}u^3+u$ to a common denominator $15$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broken down into several steps:

$$64\sqrt8(\dfrac15u^5-\dfrac23u^3+u)+C$$

Factor out $u$:

$$64\sqrt8u(\dfrac15u^4-\dfrac23u^2+1)+C$$

Factor out $\dfrac1{15}$ to remove the separate fractions:

$$\dfrac{64\sqrt8u}{15}\times15(\dfrac15u^4-\dfrac23u^2+1)+C\\
\dfrac{64\sqrt8u}{15}(3u^4-10u^2+15)+C$$